# In JSP, context.xml seems to be broken error

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat

Following is my context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Cloud_Storage" />
<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>sessioncheck.SessionCheckFilter</filter-class>
</filter>    
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <!--url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern-->
    <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
    <!-- url from where you implement the filtering -->
</filter-mapping>
```

The error i am getting is this

[Fatal Error] :3:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

F:\netbeanapp\Cloud Storage\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: Deployment error: Tomcat configuration file F:\netbeanapp\Cloud Storage\web\META-INF\context.xml seems to be broken. Please make sure it is parseable and valid.
See the server log for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` are parts of the deployment descriptor `web.xml` not `context.xml`

Reference here

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13712/web_xml.htm